# EXCEPTION open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android, exception, file-permissions

Hello Sorry for asking but I try everything.

I have a problem with this exception `open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`

my Manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

My method for get realPath

```
 private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
        Cursor cursor = mActivity.getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file
            // path
            return contentURI.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            String path = cursor.getString(idx);
            cursor.close();
            return path;
        }
    }
```

but when use this code

```
 FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
```

catch block handle this error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20171016_220009.mp4: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

My actual Path file

```
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20171016_220009.mp4
```

this is all code where used path file.

Thanks for any help I need 
The solution, I read a lot of theory but not run :) 
Please if it possible give me an example code. 
Thanks :D

Comment: It seems you are using Android M+ version. Which needs run time permission also.

Comment: You can also do one more thing to get running app right now is go to settings>>apps>>permissions and accept all permissions manually.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: I don't know what os Android M+